# Why does jsonnet python package use the name _jsonnet?

Tags: python, jsonnet

The [Python Api for Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/ref/bindings.html) uses `import _jsonnet`
Why is that? Why was it preferred over `import jsonnet` ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be because the functions are implemented in a C file

https://github.com/google/jsonnet/blob/master/python/_jsonnet.c